# Set default bin value if not present in aerospike

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, default, aerospike

Suppose I have 2 bins in aeropike set

1. **number**(key) 2. **timeLeft**

I wanted to get a **timeLeft** value from aerospike for a number.
But if the particular record is not present then I want to create the record and set a default value 6000 to **timeLeft** and then get the value in the single transaction.

```
public Record someMethod(String num) {

        WritePolicy writePolicy = aerospikeRepo.getWritePolicy(null, ttl, true);
        return aerospikeRepo.operate(writePolicy, namespace, set, num, Operation.get());

}
```

Personally, I think the .operate() method of the aerospike client will be used somehow but did not find relevant Operation to set the default value if not present.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Expressions. Here is sample code:

```
import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.WritePolicy;
import com.aerospike.client.Bin;
import com.aerospike.client.Key;
import com.aerospike.client.Record;
import com.aerospike.client.Value;
import com.aerospike.client.policy.RecordExistsAction;
import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException;
import com.aerospike.client.ResultCode;
import com.aerospike.client.Operation;

import com.aerospike.client.exp.Exp;
import com.aerospike.client.exp.ExpOperation;
import com.aerospike.client.exp.ExpWriteFlags;
import com.aerospike.client.exp.Expression;
System.out.println("Client modules imported.");

AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient("localhost", 3000);

WritePolicy wP = new WritePolicy();
wP.respondAllOps = true;
int iNumber = 11;
int iTimeLeft = 6000;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
  Key key = new Key ("test", "testset", iNumber);
  Expression tlExp = Exp.build(Exp.val(iTimeLeft));
  Record record = client.operate(wP, key, 
       ExpOperation.write("timeLeft", tlExp, ExpWriteFlags.CREATE_ONLY | ExpWriteFlags.POLICY_NO_FAIL),
       //ExpOperation.write("timeLeft", tlExp, ExpWriteFlags.DEFAULT),                          
       Operation.get("timeLeft"));   
    
  List<?> list = record.getList("timeLeft");
  System.out.println(list.get(1));  
  iTimeLeft = iTimeLeft - 1000; //should not alter record value
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Client modules imported.
6000
6000
6000
6000
6000
```

However, if I use the DEFAULT, the output will be modified each time. (what you don't want, compared to the correct flags above (CREATE_ONLY|POLICY_NO_FAIL i.e. silently go on to next operation if you want to update the record only if the bin does not exist).

```
Client modules imported.
6000
5000
4000
3000
2000
```